# How many simple Eulerian graphs (up to isomorphism) on 5 vertices are there?

Tags: graph-theory

I have considered Euler's Theorem which states that for the simple connected graph: G is Eulerian if and only if the degree of each vertex is even.

Therefore I came up with (4,4,4,4,4) and (2,2,2,2,2). However, how would I check if there are more?

Note: I need to use degree sequences.

Answer (score 3):

There are 34 simple graphs with 5 vertices, 21 of which are connected (see [link](http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes5)). There are four connected graphs on 5 vertices whose vertices all have even degree.

1. The $5$-cycle with degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,2)$: [image: List item]
2. The complete graph on $5$ vertices with degree sequence $(4,4,4,4,4)$: [image]
3. The butterfly/hourglass graph with degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,4)$: [image]
4. The following graph with degree sequence $(2,2,2,4,4)$: [image]

*A word of warning:* In general, it's not good enough to just specify the degree sequence as non-isomorphic graphs can have the same degree sequences.

**Edit.** If you want to start with a given degree sequence and determine whether there is a simple graph with that degree sequence, then the [Erdos-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) is of interest. It states the following.

A sequence of non-negative integers $d_1\geq \cdots \geq d_n$ can be represented as the degree sequence of a simple graph if and only if $d_1+d_2+\cdots + d_n$ is even, and
$$\sum_{i=1}^k d_i \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \min(d_i,k)$$
holds for every $k$ with $1\leq k \leq n$.